# Iterate throw specific xml attribute by Codesynthesis

Tags: c++, xml, codesynthesis

I have an xsd file and I want to iterate throw an special attribute on the xml belongs to it ([Here is my xsd](https://raw.github.com/percolator/percolator/master/src/xml/percolator_out.xsd)). After creating my classes by codesynthesis like below:

```
xsdcxx cxx-tree --root-element percolator_output --generate-polymorphic --namespace-map http://per-colator.com/percolator_out/14=xsd pout.xsd
```

I've writing my main like :

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
   auto_ptr<percolator_output> h (percolator_output_ (argv[1]));
   //-----percolator_output::peptides_optional& pep (h->peptides ());
   for (peptides::peptide_const_iterator i (h->peptides ().begin ()); i != h->peptides ().end (); ++i)
   {
     cerr << *i << endl;
    }
  }
  catch (const xml_schema::exception& e)
  {
   cerr << e << endl;
   return 1;
  }
}
```

I want to iterate throw the attribute "peptides" on my xml file but the output of `h->peptides ()` is `percolator_output::peptides_optional` and it's not iterator-able.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presence of the optional element first need to be confirmed by using the function `present()`. If element is present, the function `get()` can be used to return a reference to the element. I modified your code as little as possible to make it compile.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <pout.hxx>

using namespace std;
using namespace xsd;

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    auto_ptr<percolator_output> h (percolator_output_ (argv[1]));
    if (h->peptides().present())
    {
      for (peptides::peptide_const_iterator i (h->peptides ().get().peptide().begin ()); i != h->peptides ().get().peptide().end (); ++i)
      {
        cerr << *i << endl;
      }
    }
  }
  catch (const xml_schema::exception& e)
  {
   cerr << e << endl;
   return 1;
  }
}
```

And also, the command line argument `--generate-ostream` was missing to `xsdcxx`.

```
$ xsdcxx cxx-tree --root-element percolator_output --generate-polymorphic --generate-ostream --namespace-map http://per-colator.com/percolator_out/14=xsd pout.xsd
$ g++ -I. main.cc pout.cxx -lxerces-c
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 12.10 \n \l
```